# Creating Map of Unknown Space without being able to see obstacles

Tags: graphs

I'm trying to create a program where I have a user walking around a random space that contains obstacles, but I can't see where the obstacles are. The point is that as a user walks around, based on where they are traveling, the program creates a rough map of places where there aren't any obstacles (if the user is able to go over some point, there isn't an obstacle there).

Anyone have any ideas of how to approach this, or could direct me to any sources? I've looked into how GPS and other forms of mapping work but the difficulty with this program is that I don't have a pre-built map to go off of, I essentially have to create a map of a random space while blindfolded.

Comment: 1) What does *random* mean in "random space"? 2) If your space is a $n \times m$ grid and the points are cells in the grid, then you can use DFS to find all reachable points. If it's not, please describe what *space* means.

Comment: By space I mean basically a coordinate plane so their are infinitely many points. Essentially I have obstacles (rectangles for example) places around the plane which I can’t traverse over. The problem with something like DFS is that it requires me to be able to traverse the graph at will, but in this the user’s path is essentially random. Based on their path I have to create a map. Ultimately the goal is that once enough data has been collected about the surroundings, the user can input a start and destination point and the program will tell them what path to take without hitting obstacles.

Comment: Please don't leave clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question so it is self-contained, reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and has all information needed.  (Don't mark changes with "Edit:" - revise it so it reads well for someone who reads only the latest version.)  It also helps to tell us what your specific requirements are, and what approaches you've considered and why you've rejected them (which requirements do they violate?).

Comment: You can build a graph on all visited points and build the shortest paths in this graph. Since every unvisited point can potentially be an obstacle, you can't do anything else, unless you have some restrictions on the problem.

Comment: Relevant buzzwords could be "robots" and "unknown environment". There are [books](https://www.routledge.com/Autonomous-Mobile-Robots-in-Unknown-Outdoor-Environments/Zhu-Kim-Minor-Qiu/p/book/9780367572488) on the topic.